# Flex chart...update date range

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I am using Flex 4 & zend to create a simple areaseries chart. Currently, I am pulling 20 yrs of data from the database & displaying it by default. I then want to let the user choose the dates he wants, but without going back to the server....how can I do that?
`<mx:AreaChart id="Areachart" dataProvider="{employeesResult.lastResult}">`

`<mx:series>`
`<mx:AreaSeries yField="numberOfEmployees" xField="date" id="areaSeries"/>`
`</mx:series>`
`</mx:AreaChart>`

`<mx:LinkButton click="dateChange()" label="1 year" />`

private function dateChange():void{
        what goes here????
     }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rather than sticking the result of the service call straight into the graph. Keep it on a model somewhere.

If you add it into an ArrayCollection (or really anything that implements ICollectionView) you can then use the filter functions exposed by that to filter your dataset before it's fed into the graph.

You also get the advantage of being able to re-filter the results. By slicing up the array, you are altering your base data set.

Comment: something like...

<mx:ArrayCollection id="dp" source="{employeesResult.lastResult}" filterFunction="myFilterFunction" />

<mx:AreaChart id="Areachart" dataProvider="{dp}">

Answer (score 0):

add another one array and fill it like this:

for(startDate;less then endDate;iterate)
{
fill with data from employeesResult.lastResult
}

or explain what do you want in details?

Comment: test something like this: *areaSeries.dataProvider = employeesResult.lastResult.slice(0,100);* and you cannot use start index less the zero, check back your link. Also you could try myChart.invalidateDisplayList(); after changing DataProvider

Comment: thanks. That still doesn't work. employees.lastResult(0,100) returns an empty array.

Comment: okay, then give me your runnable sample with embedded data and no external service so we could do something next.

Comment: hmmm....I don't know how much better I can explain it. I am a weekend hacker, so all this is very new to me. I basically followed this: http://www.flepstudio.org/forum/flex-builder-3-eng/6089-connecting-flex-4-zend-using-flash-builder-4-a.html  
Now, I am trying to manipulate the data that is retrieved from the php.....quick note, when I put in "employeesResult.lastResult." it doesn't give me code hinting so I think putting the "slice" there is the wrong way to do it, I think.

Comment: could you determine the type of dataprovider?

Comment: I've now added a filter function, as suggested above, but no luck.
`   
       
public function filterByRange( item:Object ):Boolean 
 {
 return true;
 }
   
<s:ArrayCollection id="dg" filterFunction="filterByRange"  />
 <s:CallResponder id="getDataResult"/>
 <datadata:DataData id="dataData" />
<mx:AreaChart id="areachart1" creationComplete="getData(event)" dataProvider="{dg}" showDataTips="true">
  <mx:series>
   <mx:AreaSeries yField="price" id="areaSeries" xField="date"/>
  </mx:series>
  <mx:horizontalAxis>
   <mx:DateTimeAxis/>
  </mx:horizontalAxis>
 </mx:AreaChart>
</s:Application>

`

Comment: and the php code:

public function get() {
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->connection, "SELECT * FROM table");  
$this->throwExceptionOnError();
 
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$this->throwExceptionOnError();
 
$rows = array();
  
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $row->date, $row->price);
  
  while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
      $row->date = new DateTime($row->date);
      $rows[] = $row;
      $row = new stdClass();
      mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $row->date, $row->price);
    }
  
mysqli_stmt_free_result($stmt);
mysqli_close($this->connection);
 
   return $rows;
 }